# what the new mean in the following

Tags: c#, .net

In the interface, I saw the following

```
  public interface ITest : ITestBase
    {
        new string Item { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to know the meaning of "new" here.

Comment: Why the down vote? The question is clear and valid.

Comment: Why not just look it up in the documentation?

Comment: "Why not just look it up?" - Because it's covered by clause 3 of the FAQ (software tools commonly used by programmers): see http://stackoverflow.com/faq so, yes, you could have looked it up but that doesn't make it any less useful as a question (at least by my standards). Especially since I've used a little of C# (developed one application) and never seen that before. So, at a bare minimum, it gave _me_ more knowledge, which I consider a good thing.

Comment: @dkson: "why not just look it up" is a valid response to almost any question on this site.  The point of the site is to be the place that you can look it up, and we do that by answering questions - whether complex or simple.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The new keyword in front of a property or method is used to hide the member with the same name in a parent class that is not virtual, and is considered by many (including me) bad practice because it may in many cases don't give you the result you expect.

An example:

```
class A{
  public int Test(){ return 1; }
}

class B : A{
  public new int Test(){ return 2; }
}

B b = new B();
Console.WriteLine( b.Test() );
A b2 = new B();
Console.WriteLine( b2.Test() );
```

This will print 2 and 1 respectively, and is confusing since both objects are in fact of type B.

Comment: Here we have an interface, there is no a parent class, does it have any meaning to add the new modifier?

Comment: @Ghyath Serhal - I have never used it myself, but in the case where you have a interface that inherit from another interface that also contain the same method or property. But it's rather dirty, and I see no practical use for it in any circumstance. If anyone does, I would be glad to know.

Comment: @Ghyath Serhal: No, the `new` keyword has no meaning when applied to members that you implement. You actaully get a compiler warning that the keyword is ignored.

Comment: As Guffa said you get two kind of warnings. One when you use the new keyword, and there is no parent member with the same name. And one if there is a parent member with the same name, but you omit the new keyword.